# Issue in network configuration

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I had 2 routers from a test environment deployed at work and at server room. Both had same mac address but were connected with two different internet connections from same ISP. I spent my 5 hours trying to access server from my WORK(both are 5km apart). Then I remembered about same mac, got it changed, and now I could access my server. But I read that mac address is a local protocol that travels only till the router and not to the main Fiber cable. Then why I couldn't connect to the server??

```
          ISP                                             ISP   
 Router 1 with same mac                             Router 2 with same mac   
Client 1 with different mac -----no Connection---- Server with Different Mac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. The MAC address is used for layer 2 addressing on the same network (LAN).

`Your network (LAN1) <-ROUTER-> ISP network <-ROUTER-> Your network (LAN2)`

Although the same MAC was on different LANs on your end (which is ok) they are on the same network on your ISPs end (which is not ok).

This is a rather abstract explanation, since I don't know your ISPs infrastructure, it's difficult to go into details. Feel free to ask if you have further questions.